# Wrap a body in a soap template?

Tags: .net, xml, soap

I am trying to load the following xml in below and then replace the tokens wrapped in {} with the appropriate values, but I noticed that it complains that {} is an invalid character.  Should I just load it as a regular text file?  or is there a more simple way to do this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope {NAMESPACES}>
  <soapenv:Header>
      <From>
        <SystemId>{FROM_SYSTEM_ID}</SystemId>
        <Credential>
          <userName>{USERNAME}</userName>
          <password>{PASSWORD}</password>
        </Credential>
        <SourceId />
      </From>
      <To>
        <Address>{ADDRESS}</Address>
      </To>
      <timeStamp>{TIME_STAMP}</timeStamp>
      <echoToken>{ECHO_TOKEN}</echoToken>
      <action>{ACTION}</action>
      <transactionId>{TRANSACTION_ID}</transactionId>
  </soapenv:Header>
  <soapenv:Body>
    {BODY}
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I believe the {} is only invalid for attributes, but for it is fine for the inner xml of elements.

Comment: What platform? Java? Besides, `{}` is not part of XML, so use it where you want.

Comment: .NET. I know it is not a part of xml, that is what I already said in my message.  Is there something I can use beisdes the {} that would be valid if I load it as an xml document or should I just load it as a plain text document.

Comment: Which version of .NET, and I why do you think `{}` is ever invalid? Is there a particular exception you received when you tried to load that XML?

Comment: I ran XElement.Parse on the message and it gave the error:  
Name cannot begin with the '{' character.  It was complaining about the {NAMESPACES}, but it is fine for the elements.  I am looking for a proper place holder for attributes.

Comment: It's not a problem for attributes. It's a problem for your `{NAMESPACES}` placeholder because it's just sitting up there. You would need a syntax like `xmlns="{NAMESPACES}"` and just replace the entire "attribute" with the set of namespaces.

Comment: Yes, but what about in the case where I might have xmlns:ws, xmlns, xmlns:wsu, xmlsn:wsa.

Comment: I didn't want to do xmlns:ws={wsnamespace} for example, because their might are cases where I would not need it.

Comment: I mean that you would the syntax `xmlns="{NAMESPACES}"` as a special case, and replace that entire string with the set of namespace declarations that may be required. If none are required, then just remove that string entirely.

Comment: ok, make senses, make an answer and I will mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{}` is not a problem in attributes. It is a problem for your `{NAMESPACES}` placeholder because it's just sitting there where an attribute name was expected.

I suggest that you use a syntax like `xmlns="{NAMESPACES}"`. This should get past most XML parsers (at least, those who don't validate that a namespace should be a URI).

However, you would need to treat this as a special case. When you see this string, replace the entire string with your list of namespaces. If you have no namespaces, then you would just remove the string. Otherwise, replace it with your *entire* list of namespace declarations.